# Login to phpMyAdmin with encrypted password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.6.

I have a user "**test**" with a password, the password is MySQL encrypted, which is like '`*E494B31EA7DDA68A012783C852F1AB397877B17A`'

The only thing is I don't have the plain password, or honestly, I don't want to store them.

I want to log in to phpMyAdmin via **singon** auth type, but how do I make login using this encrypted password and not the plain password? Is there any way?

Comment: You are asking the wrong audience here. You need dba or sysadmin to configure single sign on. You do  not need programmers for this.

Comment: Could you please explain what "sign on" means? Single sign on?

Comment: "single sign on" means configuring your system to trust some other source for authentication (rather than storing hashed passwords).  presumably that is being suggested because you say "I don't want to store them".  It isn't clear to me if you meant plaintext passwords or even hashed passwords though.

Answer (score 1):

In a word, no.

The point of these hashed passwords is that it's possible to validate the plain text password without storing in in a form that can be retrieved by an intruder to your database.

Comment: Then how cPanel creates a direct login to phpMyAdmin? I don't think cPanel is storing my MySQL user password in plain text. There must be some way.

Comment: phpmyadmin sends your plain password to mysql, which hashes it and compares it to the stored hash.    not sure what you mean by a direct login

Answer (score -1):

phpMyAdmin isn’t a database, it’s just an aggregation tool. To login to phpMyAdmin, you’ll have to use the username and password setup on your MySQL database.

MySQL comes with a default user/pass, but it lets you add your own users for accessing the database. By default, the passwords are encrypted when created via the MySQL command line.

If you have a hashed/encrypted password and need to find out what the plain text value is, you can usually search it up and find out online, as hash algorithms like MD5 are no longer considered secure because most of the common hashes have been cracked.

Comment: Both phpmyadmin and mysql support single sign on.